# Label text wont update

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a program to help with Active Directory management, my problem is whenever I try and update a label in my info panel it wont change! I know its running because I placed a `Debug.Writeline(Name)` that is working great. It just doesn't change the value of the label in the program.

```
public void UpdateInfoPanel(string Name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Users.Count; i++)
    {
        if(Users[i].DisplayName == Name)
        {
            this.LabelNameText.Text = Name.ToString();
            this.LabelNameText.Refresh();
            Debug.WriteLine(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this from the UI thread?

Comment: Aside: Parameter `string Name`, `Name.ToString();`? Isn't that a bit redundant?

Comment: I originally didnt have the ToString() or the "this." but im just trying everything at this point, and im running this on the Form that hosts the Label.

Comment: it seems to be long running task, I don't see the `break` once user name matches. if there are thousands of users in the array, then it will take time to refresh the UI.

Comment: I will definitely have to add that for performance but right now i'm deployed on a test environment with two users.

Comment: I think what @Vinit is getting at is the label won't update until the message loop gets a chance to be evaluated. `UpdateInfoPanel()` and its callers usually need to return before that happens. You can force it to go early by calling `Application.DoEvents()` (for example, in your loop), but you should avoid that if possible.

Comment: You should add a `break;` statement at the end of the `if` block to exit the loop as soon as you find a match.

Comment: The way I did it in my app is by adding a `this.UpDate()` after changing the label text to update the form

Comment: The looping does seem utterly superfluous as you pass in name then loop to find a matching User then just set the label text to name. What happens if you strip out the loop and condition and just set this.LabelNameText.Text = Name;?

Comment: This whole function seems redundant. i mean you can only hold one name in your text box, you are displaying the name you are searching for.. Ergo you could replace the whole method with `LabelNameText.Text = Name` no looping

Comment: A better way to do this would be `var user = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DisplayName == Name);`
        `if (user != null)`
           `LabelNameText.Text = user.DisplayName();` now as to why its not updating, is your are probably stuck in a massive loop where the UI wont get a chance to update, we need more information

Comment: You can at least bail from the loop if you find a match. That way you found it in the last place you looked.

Comment: Thank everyone for all your help. I have added the break and this.update() to no avail. I did however just drop the entire loop as per some advice and reworked it. thanks again!